# Writing code to print out the data type of variables

Tags: python, types

I am new to python. I have to print the data type for a few variables.

However, the variable tripped me up. The input file is the variable which is a csv data file.

Now I am confused, does that mean the xlsx file or each data type within that file?

Here is how I go about finding simple variable data types:

input_file = 25.
print("the type of input_file is", type(input_file))

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really have enough information to begin coding; maybe you can share the exact instructions you've been given and we can see if it's not as ambiguous as you think?

Comment: It is just: "write your code to print the type for these variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"write your code to print the type for these variables" sounds like you have
some existing code. Then someone gave a requirement to add code to print the
type for each variable in "your code."

```
input_file = 25.
print("the type of input_file is", type(input_file))

# If one of your variables is a csv file the approach would be the
# same.
data_file = open('data.csv','w')
print("the type of data_file is", type(data_file))
```

Demonstration run:

```
the type of input_file is <class 'float'>
the type of data_file is <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```